# Keyboard shortcut for changing order of spaces

Tags: spaces, mission-control

I haven't found anything natively in MacOS to do this, but is there a workaround? maybe with making a script in Automator or something like that?

Comment: Spaces is notoriously unscriptable. I'd just drag them ;)